# Implications of using backtick (inline code) markup for Russian text

Tags: discussion

User @Mołot reached me in a comment raising concerns about using backtick notation for visual markup. De-facto this kind of markup has been used quite often at Russian SE by many users (including me) since it make it easier to visually separate the word or phrase discussed from context.

What I want to do next is to gather information about how this affects specifically Russian text. What I want to discuss here is:

- What is the list most of most popular software on all major platforms, desktop and mobile.
- How exactly this kind of markup affects pronunciation of Russian words in all this software.
- What are other aspects we should keep in mind for making decision whether it's ok or not ok to use backtick markup.

related - [Does using code syntax for non-code content causes accessibility issues?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328858/does-using-code-syntax-for-non-code-content-causes-accessibility-issues)

UPD: I've deleted comments because I had two options either to move all comments to forum - and actually there are some comments relevant to the question above - or just delete irrelevant ones. Here's a screenshot of our discussion:

[image]